# Bulk Import CSV file into SQL Server - remove double quotes

Tags: sql-server

I am running SQL 2008, bulk insert command, while inserting the data, I am trying to remove (") double quotes from the CSV file, which works partially, but doesnt work for all the records, please check my code and the screenshot of the result.

```
Bulk Insert tblUsersXTemp 
 from 'C:\FR0250Members161212_030818.csv'
 WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","', 
 ROWTERMINATOR = '"\n"',
 --FormatFile =''
 ERRORFILE = 'C:\bulk_insert_BadData.txt')
```

[image]

Comment: Are the rows that have a problem the first and last of the CSV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you do the bulk insert, you could replace the double quotes.

```
UPDATE tblUsersXTemp
SET usxMembershipID = REPLACE(usxMembershipID, CHAR(34), '')
```

Comment: What does CHAR(34) signify here?

Comment: @psam the quotes

Answer (score 1):

You need a format file I believe, that's what I think is going on.

> If you use the following Bulk Insert command to import the data without using a format file, then you will land up with a quotation mark prefix to the first column value and a quotation mark suffix for the last column values and a quotation mark prefix for the first column values.

[Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file/)

Example from reference:

```
BULK INSERT tblPeople
   FROM ‘bcp.txt’
   WITH (
      DATAFILETYPE=‘char’,
      FIELDTERMINATOR=‘","’,
      ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\n’,
      FORMATFILE = ‘bcp.fmt’);
```

You could also potentially have dirty data that uses quotes for more than just delimiters.